# How to retrieve a document's id which is defined by Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question about how to retrieve the **`id`** of a document. The **ids** are defined by Firestore and I can't retrieve a specific document by the **id**.
For example, in the example below, Let's say I wanna get a document retrieved by its **id**, `2tg00......`. When I console.logged a quiz I clicked, I could see the quiz info, but except the id. Do I have to write an own function to get a specific document??

Thanks for your time in advance.

[image]

```js
quizzes.map((quiz, quizIndex) => (
            <div className='eachQuizContainer' key={quiz.index}>
              <div className='quizQuestionContainer'>
                <span className='quizIndex'>{quizIndex + 1}.</span>
                <p className='quizQuestion'>{quiz.question}</p>
                {console.log(quiz)}
              </div>
    
              {quiz.user.uid && uid === quiz.user.uid ? (
                <div className='icons'>
                  <Link
                    to={{ pathname: `/kinniku-quiz/edit/${quiz.id}` }}
                    state={{ quiz: quiz }}
                  >
                    <i className='riEditBoxLine'>{riEditBoxLine}</i>
                  </Link>
                  <i
                    className='riDeleteBinLine'
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(quiz.id)}
                  >
                    {riDeleteBinLine}
                  </i>
                </div>
              ) : quiz.user.uid && uid !== quiz.user.uid ? (
                <Link
                  to={{ pathname: `/profile/${quiz.user.uid}` }}
                  state={{ user: quiz.user }}
                >
                  <img
                    src={quiz.user.photoURL}
                    alt={quiz.user.username}
                    referrerPolicy='no-referrer'
                  />
                </Link>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          ))
```

I call this getQuizzes function in useEffect() too.

```js
  const getQuizzes = async (ctg='', tag='') => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'quizzes');
    let q = query(
      collectionRef,
      orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    );
    if (ctg !== "") {
      q = query(q, where('category', '==', ctg));
    }
    if (tag !== '') {
      q = query(q, where('tags', 'array-contains', tag));
    }
    const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
    console.log(snapshot.docs);
    setQuizzes(snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
      doc.data().id = "quiz-";
      console.log("first useeffect", doc.data().id);
      return doc.data();
    }));
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

Comment: You have the feature to create firestore documents using your custom ids (in that case you'll know the exact id), or you can get the reference of the document when you create it. That reference has the id included. Now it's your concern how you handle it.

Comment: code sample : 
`async function addCity(newCity) {
  const { id } = await db.collection("cities").add(newCity)
  console.log("the new city's id:", id)
}`

Comment: Can you show the code where you get `quizzes`? The ID is delivered as a key on the snapshot item, so instead of calling `quiz.data()` to get the contents of the quiz document, you would call `quiz.id`.

Comment: You may have a look at this [thread](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/how+to+get+document+id+in+firestore).